# Undefined index in array, but it is there

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. Here is it's var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["139"]=>
  string(5) "my_data"
}
```

We see, that we have key 139, and it's string (var dumps of key: *string(3) "139"*).
I want to get element from array, here's the code:

```
$bad_array = $this->get('some_data');

var_dump($bad_array);
var_dump($my_key);
var_dump(isset($bad_array[$my_key]));
var_dump($bad_array[$my_key]);
```

Here's the output:

```
array(1) {
  ["139"]=>
  string(5) "my_data"
}
string(3) "139" // my key output
bool(false) // it's not isset
Notice: Undefined index: 139 in /my_file_path.php on line 89
NULL
```

**WHY**??? I have a string variable, all of keys are strings. How can it be?

Comment: It's odd that you get `string(5)` for `"my_data"`

Comment: Try `var_dump(bin2hex($my_key), bin2hex(key($bad_array)))` and see what you get.

Comment: Please post your code that constructs the array.

Comment: @Ryan for me it looks like that this is the value for `var_dump($bad_array);` @HAL9000 it contains `string(3) "139"` as you can see

Comment: @Ryan. It's my mistake. I changed the code in post slightly for clarity. There is 5char string in my app.

Comment: @deceze: bin2hex of $my_key: string(6) "313339", bin2hex of key in array: string(6) "313339". But isset is still FALSE.

Comment: That's... plain weird. :)

Comment: In some versions of PHP there is automatic cast of strings to ints

Comment: If your var_dump output is in a browser, can you check that there are no special characters (html entities that could be removed, or any weird thing) in the source of the page ?

Comment: I found bug. I had $some_data = json_decode(json_encode($some_data)); in my code. Then I do (array)$some_data to get array. Here comes the trouble. If i will do json_decode(json_encode($some_data), true), without cast to array - it will work good.

Comment: @sebcap26: in console

Comment: @NikitaKuhta so you've solved your problem?

Comment: Yes. I will post answer soon. But it's strange.

Comment: `json_decode()` creates objects by default. Those show up as `object(stdClass)` in var_dump, never as array.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I converts object to array by: (array)$my_data.

Comment: @RoyalBg Your comment was actually the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

`Array` type-casting from an `Object` [doesn't work with integer properties (as `strings` i.e. "139")](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting).

**Long answer**

A bunch of testing code :

```
<pre>
<?php
  $arr = array("139" => "some_data", "test" => "other_data");
  
  $good = (object) $arr;
  $good_arr = (array) $good;
  
  $bad = json_decode(json_encode($arr));
  $bad_arr = (array)($bad);
  
  var_dump ($arr);
  foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    var_dump (gettype ($k));    // 139 is integer
  
  var_dump ($good);
  foreach ($good as $k => $v)
    var_dump (gettype ($k));    // 139 is integer
    
  var_dump ($good_arr);
  foreach ($good_arr as $k => $v)
    var_dump (gettype ($k));    // 139 is integer

  var_dump ($bad);
  foreach ($bad as $k => $v)
    var_dump (gettype ($k));    // 139 is string

  var_dump ($bad_arr);
  foreach ($bad_arr as $k => $v)
    var_dump (gettype ($k));    // 139 is string

  var_dump ($arr[139]);         // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($arr["139"]);       // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($arr["test"]);      // string(10) "other_data"
  
  var_dump ($good->{139});      // NULL
  var_dump ($good->{"139"});    // NULL
  var_dump ($good->{"test"});   // string(10) "other_data"
  
  var_dump ($good_arr[139]);    // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($good_arr["139"]);  // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($good_arr["test"]); // string(10) "other_data"
  
  var_dump ($bad->{139});       // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($bad->{"139"});     // string(9) "some_data"
  var_dump ($bad->{"test"});    // string(10) "other_data"
  
  var_dump ($bad_arr[139]);     // NULL
  var_dump ($bad_arr["139"]);   // NULL
  var_dump ($bad_arr["test"]);  // string(10) "other_data"
?>
</pre>
```

`bin2hex` is actually showing exactly the same value, and `foreach` was working fine.

So how is that possible that it doesn't work when we're trying to access it directly ?
And how weird is it that the last is displaying fine ?

Well, actually, I got the answer to the second question from this [part from the doc talking about array type casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)
As you can see there, when converting an object to array with type casting, this doesn't work for number properties, which are let inaccessible.

For the first question, I will assume that the type cast doesn't change how data are represented in memory, so that it can still iterate on it as if it was an object.

Next are just my assumptions of differences between both scenarios :

*In the good scenario*

`PHP` is handling stuff all by himself. An array key of type `string` representing an `integer` is automatically converted to `integer`.
Then, no problem when we convert it, it becomes a property (with `integer` type) of the `$good` object even though it isn't accessible (because it is trying to reach the `"139"` property, not the `139`). (`NULL` returned)
When we do the cast to array `$good_arr`, the data structure hasn't changed, and we can still access it, because it reaches `139` and not `"139"`.

*In the bad scenario*

Here the object is regenerated by `json_decode`. This function doesn't generate bad objects (and tht's a good thing !), so all the properties will have type `string`.
This is why we can access the property directly from the object here. It is a valid property (type `string`) so we can access it.
But as told in the docs, when we cast it back to `array`, the data structure hasn't changed, so we can't access it. Either we write `$bad_arr[139]` or `$bad_arr["139"]` it will try to access to the value with the key `139` (`NULL` returned), when it should actually access `"139"`.

**Conclusion**

This is a typical example of `PHP`'s magic. Converting `string`s to `int` automatically in arrays is what caused your problem.

So your solution of using the `assoc` param of `json_decode` seems to be the only one which will work here :

```
json_decode($json_arr, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an array, then I saves it to redis. After save I casts array to object through json_decode(json_encode($ar)) construction.

```
$redis->save($array);
$this->object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
...
```

Then I casts in to array again:

```
$ar = (array)$this->obj;
```

If I will do it, I can't access array properties.
**Solution**:

```
$this->object = json_decode(json_encode($array), true); // get array
...
if (is_object($ar)) {
    $ar = (array)$ar;
}
```

Strange things...